# Can I set a custom caption image for the Video sent over WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video

Videos sent and received on WhatsApp has one of the ***random*** frame from video as caption image.
Any idea, how this image is chosen and is it possible to change it?

For example in my 01:06 min video, the caption image is from frame 00:39